# Single quotes replace in Java

Tags: java

In Java I have:

```
String str = "Welcome 'thanks' How are you?";
```

I need to replace the single quotes in `str` by `\'`, that is, when I print `str` I should get output as `Welcome \'thanks\' How are you`.

Comment: So, what’s the question. Did you look in the documentation? Did you **search** using your question title? (I did: it turns up plenty of results.)

Comment: What about a string like: `how 'are' \' you`? (i.e. one is already escaped)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It looks like perhaps you want something like this:

```
    String s = "Hello 'thanks' bye";
    s = s.replace("'", "\\'");
    System.out.println(s);
    // Hello \'thanks\' bye
```

This uses [`String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method to do string replacement. Remember that `\` is an escape character for Java string literals; that is, `"\\'"` contains 2 characters, a backslash and a single quote.

#### References

- [JLS 3.10.6 Escape Sequences for Character and String Literals](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.6)

Comment: no it does not work.......any ways i found it's working 


String str="welcome'deepak";
  String str1="\\";
  String str3="\'";
  String str5=str1+str3;
  System.out.println(""+str.replace("'",str5));


welcome\'deepak

Comment: @dpaksp, it **does** work. If it doesn't, you didn't copy-paste correctly.

Answer (score 17):

Use

```
"Welcome 'thanks' How are you?".replaceAll("'", "\\\\'")
```

You need two levels of escaping in the replacement string, one for Java, and one for the regular expression engine.

Comment: A couple a (small) nitpicks: the second string is not a *regex-string* but a *regex-replacement-string* , but you are right that it needs extra escaping since it is used to escape the meta character `$` in such a string (and itself, of course). Also, there is no need to use `relaceAll(...)` in this case: `replace(...)` does the trick here.

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me:

```
"Welcome 'thanks' How are you?".replaceAll("\\'", "\\\\'");
```

It prints:

```
Welcome \'thanks\' How are you?
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you come to this question like me with trying to escape for MySQL, you want to add a second single quote to escape:

```
str.replaceAll("\\'","\\'\\'")
```

This would print:

```
Welcome ''thanks'' How are you?
```

Comment: `str.replaceAll("'", "\'\'")` did work for me for Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused, do we get different result base on Java version? or do we have not tested answers here?

And here is what did work for me:

```java
str.replaceAll("'", "\\'")
```

And this code(which is accepted answer)

```
str.replace("'", "\\'")
```

Only changes first quote.

My `java -version`:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_252-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.252-b09, mixed mode)
```